# Appsody init fails - requesting to upggrade Docker

Tags: docker, appsody

I am trying to initialise an appsody application on my MacOS Catalina, however the *appsody init* command fails with message:

*`[Error] The required version of Docker to use this stack is >= 17.09.0 - Please upgrade.`*

The thing is, I am using Docker engine version 19.03.13, so higher than 17, nowhere to upgrade from here.
Does anyone know what to do in such case?

Answer (score 2):

It's been fixed in version 0.6.5 of Appsody. Make sure you upgrade to that version. https://github.com/appsody/appsody/issues/1008

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by downgrading my Docker Desktop. First, I uninstalled the latest version then installed V18.06.1 which I downloaded from here:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-17120-ce-mac49-2018-01-19